# What options do I have to seek further compensation from Turkish Airlines for the delay in delivering my baggage?

Tags: compensation, turkish-airlines, lost-luggage

Turkish Airlines lost my baggage and it took them six days to deliver it to me. This delay caused me to spend almost $2k because I had nothing to wear and the next day was a holiday. I didn't even have shoes.

I just received notice that Turkish Airlines will only compensate me $300, which is a joke. What are my options?

Comment: Turkish Airlines describes the process here https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/any-questions/lost-and-delayed-baggage/. The terms and conditions mention "liability limits" but I can't find those anywhere.  In the US the limits are regulated but apparently not for Turkey

Comment: What did you do during this six days that required you to spend $2k? Did you need super fancy clothes because you attended a business meeting or something? To me, $300 sounds like a reasonable amount to buy clothes for one week, even if you have to buy shoes...

Comment: I’m not sure it changes anything for delayed luggage, but just in case, can you let us know the origin and destination countries? The Montreal Convention probably applies, but the rules in case of delayed baggage are complex. See https://www.forbes.com/advisor/travel-rewards/montreal-convention-luggage/

Comment: To @Hilmar: I don't find that link helpful.

Comment: To @Sabine: Yes, those 6 days were Jewish holidays, so I needed to buy formal suits, shirts, shoes, etc. Not to mention non-clothing expenses...

Comment: To @jcaron it was NYC-->TLV.

Comment: @David the Montreal Convention gives a higher limit of about $1800 so unless the airline gives a higher limit you definitely won’t get more than that. Now the issue is going to be a debate about what is “reasonable”. See the article I linked to above for a few examples of what is and what isn’t, but that leaves a lot of middle ground.

Comment: If you had travel insurance you should be able to claim on that less the $300 offered by the airline.

Comment: Does anyone know if they have an appeals process, or who I can speak to within the organization?

Comment: Did anyone figure out the process to file the delayed baggage claim? I'm in the same boat. received baggage 10 days late. My expense is within $300 though.